# Linux ssh passwordless login doesn't work?

Tags: linux, ssh

```
bharathi-1397@bharathi-1397:~$ ssh-keygen 
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/local/bharathi-1397/.ssh/id_rsa): 
/home/local/bharathi-1397/.ssh/id_rsa already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? y
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/local/bharathi-1397/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/local/bharathi-1397/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
de:e3:e5:f6:a3:8e:83:76:f0:7d:d6:e1:b3:d6:cc:93 bharathi-1397@bharathi-1397
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|        S        |
|       ...     . |
|        .+o.. .++|
|        o.+=o +E=|
|       . .o++=oo+|
+-----------------+
```

Next i copy content's from .ssh/id_rsa.pub and stored in remote machine.

```
 bharathikannan.r@172.20.2.7:~$ mkdir .ssh
 bharathikannan.r@172.20.2.7:~$ vi authorized_keys
```

paste the copied content into authorized_keys but next time i try to login it will ask password why ?
       ssh bharathikannan.r@172.20.2.7
       bharathikannan.r@172.20.2.7's password:

Why it asking password ? . I follow the step's correctly . I don't know why it ask password ?

```
ssh -v bharathikannan.r@172.20.2.7
OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-7ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.0e 6 Sep 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to integ-build3 [192.168.5.173] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/local/bharathi-1397/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/local/bharathi-1397/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/local/bharathi-1397/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/local/bharathi-1397/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/local/bharathi-1397/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/local/bharathi-1397/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH_4*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-7ubuntu1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 66:3e:67:25:65:22:f0:70:3d:e3:ce:3b:14:49:7e:76
debug1: Host '172.20.2.7' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/local/bharathi-1397/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/local/bharathi-1397/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/local/bharathi-1397/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/local/bharathi-1397/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
bharathikannan.r@172.20.2.7's password:
```

Comment: Try doing chmod 700 on your .ssh directory you're creating and/or chmod 600 on your authorized_keys file, I'm fairly sure ssh doesn't like it to be world readable.

Comment: @joachim 

I modified permissions for .ssh directory to 700 in both machines . Still i face this problem.

Comment: Could you post the output of using ssh -v to connect? That should give more info what's wrong.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson 

I am posted ssh -v output in my post .

Comment: Your client machine is correctly connecting and offering the key, and it seems the remote is accepting public key authentication but for some reason doesn't find your key in authorized_keys. Checking permissions on my machines, .ssh is chmod 700, authorized_keys is chmod 600 and it works well. Changing authorized_keys to 644 (the default) gives the same effect you're getting, but that may depend how "paranoid" your system's ssh configuration is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to your description you created the .ssh directory in your home and then created the .authorized_keys file in the same directory (your home, not in ~/.ssh/). Please make sure the file is at the correct place.

Also, the following command can set you up without all the hassle:

```
user@host:~$ ssh-copy-id user@otherhost
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6):

You probably had no ~/.ssh directory or no .ssh/authorized_keys file. Be aware when simply creating the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file manually you can easily get one of the permissions wrong.

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub  
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
restorecon -R ~/.ssh
```

The real gotcha is the last one, SELINUX (this is what I stumbled on, I always do). You can always try setting it to permissive and/or checking the audit.log too.

```
# ll -Z ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
# restorecon -R ~/.ssh
# ll -Z ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Failing all this login to the target machine and create the full key structure with

```
ssh-keygen
```

Comment: I ran into this bug on CentOS 6.  `restorecon -R -v ~/.ssh` needed to be run.

Comment: I just realized that authorized_keys is a file, and not a folder. thanks for clearing this up! Now it works on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

It's asking for a password because you haven't told the client machine what key to use.

You can do this one of two ways:

1) when you terminal into your remote machine, use the following:

`ssh -i /path/to/your/privatekey user@host`

2) Create the file `~/.ssh/config` on your client machine and insert the following:

```
Host your.hostname.tld
IdentityFile /path/to/your/privatekey
```

Method 1 is great if you have several different keys your want to use. Method 2 is effectively automatic every time you connect to the given host.

Comment: Should not be necessary - a key named `id_rsa` will be found automatically.

Comment: This worked for me. My key wasn't named id_rsa, but by following +Justin's instructions it is now working as expected! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `.ssh` dir should be `700` on both systems.

```
drwx------ .ssh
```